# how can I wildcard PHP exceptions in HTML

Tags: php

When I use something like:

```
<?php if ($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] == '/index.html'): ?>
// Only Show in Index
<?php endif; ?>
```

to set something to only display in the specified page. Is there a way to wildcard the pages? For example, setting it to only display on a wildcard of pages in a directory `'/posts/*'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `preg_match()`. The documentation can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).

Example of usage:

```
<?php if (preg_match('%^/index.html%',$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])): ?>
// Only Show in Index
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (preg_match('/\/posts\//', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) === 1)
```

or

```
if (strpos('/posts/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) !== false)
```